# Spring boot conection Redshift sequence

Tags: amazon-web-services, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, amazon-redshift

I´m trying to run my app with spring boot and JPA conecting on Redshift database without success.
A search in google found some people with this same problem but the sugestion is change for RDS or another database but i have not this option.
In Redshift the information_schema.sequences doesn´t exist, so i shoud find a way to round this issue

The problem is:

**Invalid operation: relation "information_schema.sequences" does not exist;**

In the Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazon.redshift</groupId>
        <artifactId>redshift-jdbc4</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.10.1009</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

In my aplication.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.amazon.redshift.jdbc4.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:redshift://redshift-cluster-1.xxxxxxxx.us-west-2.redshift.amazonaws.com:xxxx/db
spring.datasource.username=xxxxxxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxxxxxx

spring.datasource.testWhileIdle = true
spring.datasource.validationQuery = SELECT 1

spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect =  org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation = true 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class =org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContex
```

But on start aplication the console shows:

> 2019-11-27 23:48:50.414 ERROR 16608 --- [           main]
>   o.h.e.j.e.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl   : Could not fetch the
>   SequenceInformation from the database   java.sql.SQLException:
>   Amazon Invalid operation: relation
>   "information_schema.sequences" does not exist;    at
>   com.amazon.redshift.client.messages.inbound.ErrorResponse.toErrorException(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleErrorResponse(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.handleMessage(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   com.amazon.jdbc.communications.InboundMessagesPipeline.getNextMessageOfClass(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]  at
>   com.amazon.redshift.client.PGMessagingContext.doMoveToNextClass(Unknown
>   Source) ~[na:na]  at...
>   Caused by: com.amazon.support.exceptions.ErrorException:
>   Amazon Invalid operation: relation
>   "information_schema.sequences" does not exist;    ... 54 common frames
>   omitted   2019-11-27 23:48:51.487  WARN 16608 --- [           main]
>   o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 500310,
>   SQLState: 42P01 2019-11-27 23:48:51.487 ERROR 16608 --- [
>   main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Amazon
>   Invalid operation: relation "information_schema.sequences" does not
>   exist;

If anybody help me i´ll be very thankfull!!!!

Comment: Do you have any Entities annoted in your code?

Comment: I Have tested creating a entity and anotate @Entity, but also unsuccess!

Comment: Having the same issue after upgrading from Spring Boot 2.0.2 to 2.3.6. Any luck solving it?